# How to make base for important function for all activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have one function for check user internet connection but I have to use that code on all activities for check user internet connectivity. If the user is not connected with the internet then the user gets saved news from SQLite.

Just want to know how to use this Any on different Activities.

A useful question for Everyone :

1. For Retrofit Call from API's.
2. For Sharedpreferences.
3. For User Helper Function similar to Given code

**Just For Example:**

```
public boolean isConnected() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    final String command = "ping -c 1 google.com";
    return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor() == 0;
}
```

Comment: Make it `static` and put in in an abstract utilities class.

Comment: @f1sh can you provide the code as i am new java android development

Comment: It will be useful for other user they can use this technique for their application

Comment: This is very broad of a question. You could use a Utility class, Kotlin extensions, handle this on a UseCase layer... please refine as there won't be a single good answer.

Comment: @shkschneider this answer will help new developers for easy coding. Don't you think shk?

Comment: Sure, any tutorial would do. But this website likes concise questions, not tutorials. It was just a comment, I did not flag the question ;)

Comment: @shkschneider i asked because everyone require one function in every activity as you know sometime developer need easy way to go through problem. if developer have one setup then he can use access from any activity. I asked this question because of Retrofit Calls if you know they are very big.Thanks for not flagging my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create Kotlin file, e.g. named `Utils`;
2. Create function in this file, and add Context parameter:

   ```
   fun isConnected(ctx: Context): Boolean {
       val cm = ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
       val activeNetwork =cm.activeNetworkInfo
       return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting
   }
   ```

   If you intend to use it only in `Activity` you can create **extension** function on `Activity` class without `Context` parameter:

   ```
   fun Activity.isConnected(): Boolean {
       val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
       val activeNetwork =cm.activeNetworkInfo
       return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting
   }
   ```
3. Call that function from wherever you want. If you call it from
   `Activity` just use code:

   ```
   isConnected(this@YourActivity)
   ```

   If you created **extension** function, just call it in `Activity`
   without passing any parameters:

   ```
   isConnected()
   ```

Comment: Thanks, But can you make this code multiple functions like if i want to use retrofit and shared preference together.

Comment: To check internet connectivity you need access to `Context`, you can use first example of the function like this: `Utils.isConnected(context)` if you call it not from the `Activity`

Comment: In this Context I would see two main options: Java would use a `BaseActivity` with protected method; Kotlin would use an extension for `Activity` wich exposes the Context indeed. Acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

> For **Kotlin Developers**:

Make one kotlin class,

**MainApp.kt** :

```
class MainApp : Application() {
    lateinit var API: API
    lateinit var savedData: SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        MainApp.appContext = applicationContext
        TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SERIF", "fonts/hn.ttf");
        initializeConfigs()
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var userHelper: UserHelper
    }

    private fun initializeConfigs(){
        savedData = getSharedPreferences("Proj", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        userHelper = UserHelper(savedData)
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor(userHelper)).build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        API = retrofit.create(API::class.java)
    }

    fun getUserHelper(): UserHelper{
        return userHelper
    }
}
```

Make Kotlin file for API
**Api** :

```
interface API {
    @POST("api/guest")
    fun registerGuest(): Call<UserTokens>
}
```

Make Another Class for **UserHelper.kt** :

```
class UserHelper(val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences) {
        public boolean isConnected() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
                final String command = "ping -c 1 google.com";
                return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor() == 0;
       }
}
```